Finding 1 in strings separated by comma, but not 11 in R with grep or grepl
Let's say I have the following strings in a column:
X1
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
0, 1, 11, 2, 3
11, 111, 1111, 11111, 1111111
11, 111, 1111, 1, 111111, 1111111

read.table(text="X1
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
0, 1, 11, 2, 3
11, 111, 1111, 11111, 1111111
11, 111, 1111, 1, 111111, 1111111", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

How could I grep or grepl any rows which contain only the number 1?
X1
**1**, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
0, **1**, 11, 2, 3 
11, 111, 1111, **1**, 111111, 1111111

but not
11,111,1111,11111,1111111


Something like grep("^1,|[ ,]1,|[ ,]1$", df$X1)

That seems to be working: df$X1[grep("^1,|[ ,]1,| 1$", df$X1)] You could write the answer

use boundary `\b``:
grep("\\b1\\b", df$X1)
[1] 1 2 4

You could view by using the str_view function:
stringr::str_view(df$X1, "\\b1\\b")
[1] │ <1>, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
[2] │ 0, <1>, 11, 2, 3
[4] │ 11, 111, 1111, <1>, 111111, 1111111

